# ng-disable with few options (refactor needed)

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for help with refactoring my code. I wrote this:

```
button.btn.btn-primary ng-click="ok()" ng-show="!params.page_name && !image_thumb" ng-disabled="(!params.project_name || !logo_thumb)" Ok, create
button.btn.btn-primary ng-click="ok()" ng-show="params.page_name || image_thumb" ng-disabled="(!params.page_name || !image_thumb)" Ok, create
```

First condition is:

```
(!params.project_name || !logo_thumb)
```

Second condition is

```
(!params.page_name || !image_thumb) if params.page_name || !image_thumb
```

but I would like use only one button with ng-disabled. Do you have any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine ANDs `&&` and  ORs `||` with parans to get a combination of the things you want.

```
button.btn.btn-primary ng-click="ok()" ng-show="(!params.page_name && !image_thumb) || params.page_name || image_thumb" ng-disabled="((!params.page_name && !image_thumb) && (!params.project_name || !logo_thumb)) || ((params.page_name || image_thumb) && (!params.page_name || !image_thumb))" Ok, create
```